# Expand filepath pattern stored in variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following value stored in a variable - pattern

```
$WS/*.asd
```

In my environment $WS evaluates to valid directory(/home/administrator/dev/workspaces/). There are some .asd files in this directory. I want to expand the `pattern` variable to all matching .asd files in this directory. However, I've tried the following commands, but neither of them works:

```
expand "$pattern"
expand: $WS/*.asd: No such file or directory

ls $pattern
ls: cannot access $WS/*.asd: No such file or directory

eval $pattern
/home/administrator/dev/workspaces/a.asd: Permission denied

echo $pattern
$WS/*.asd
```

I get the pattern as input. Any idea how I can expand the pattern to a list which includes all matching files.

**EDIT**: Explain the problem in more details

I may get any combination of env-vars and wildcards in any sequence. For example the input may be: `/home/$USER/*/$DIR/*.my_extension`. The problem is i want to evaluate all env-vars and expand the wildcards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than `eval` you can try this `find`:

```
pattern='$WS/*.asd'

find "$WS" -name "${pattern##*/}"
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question, it seems you will have to use:

```
eval echo "$pattern"
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't explanatory enough. This solution assumes I know how to extract the directory. I may get any sequence of env-vars and wildcards. For example `/home/$USER/*/$DIR/*.my_extension".

Comment: Hmm in that case `eval echo "$pattern"`

Comment: Thank you. Really, this works just as I need it to work. Please, edit your answer by putting that into it and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the elements following that pattern in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=()
shopt -s nullglob # expand the glob pattern to a null sting if no elements caught
arr+=($WS/*.asd)
shopt -u nullglob # undo the 'shopt -s nullglob'
```

To print the entries:

```
for entry in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$entry"
done
```